# Unable to push to Heroku due to a package version being 0

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've created my heroku repository that uses python-3.6.9. On an attempt to push to the master branch, the push fails due to pkg-resources being version 0 in my requirements file.

error:

```
       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_X/requirements.txt (line 12)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_X/requirements.txt (line 12))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

requirements (pip freeze > requirements.txt):

```
asgiref==3.2.7
astroid==2.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.6
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.7
pylint==2.5.2
pytz==2020.1
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.1
typed-ast==1.4.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Comment: Where did you think that would come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s a bug of `pip frozen > requirements.txt` command, you should remove string `pkg-resources==0.0.0` manually from your file.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install `pkg-resources==0.0.0`, change the version to a correct value. There is no 0.0.0 version